# Making a two-tone object in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to make an object, specifically a letter or a number, two-toned. I mean that I want to slice it in half and make the halves different colour. I think I know how to do this on Illustrator, but is there a viable way to do it in Indesign? I've gotten so far as to create outlines of the number but I don't know how to proceed. Would the fastest way be to just make it on Illustrator and copy it? If so, no need to instruct me on that, but I'd rather do it within Indesign if possible. I've attached an image for reference.

[image]

I want the upper half to be teal and lower half black.

Answer (score 3):

Once outlined the number:

- Create a rectangle covering the half of it

[image: Rectangle]

- **Menu Edit** > **Cut**
- Select the number shape
- **Menu Edit** > **Paste Into**

[image: Paste into]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Just like Illustrator, InDesign can access the Pathfinder to combine two paths. You can find it under <kbd>Window > Object & Layout > Pathfinder</kbd>. Select both outlined shape and rectangle, choose <kbd>Overlap</kbd> and copy and reflect the result. If avaiable (not in my CS6 version), <kbd>Divide</kbd> is even better.